# How to draw circle with leaflet.draw and CRS.Simple

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet.draw plugin, working on a simple image with `L.CRS.Simple`.
The drawing toolbar works fine except for drawing circles.

http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/kapi/edit?html,output

How to enable drawing circles on a Leaflet map with Leaflet.draw plugin when using `L.CRS.Simple`?

Comment: There **is** a circle added, but its radius is instantly very big, covering the entire map, hence user may think there is nothing. Might be a bug when combined with `L.CRS.Simple`.

Comment: hey @ghybs you are right, just latlng issue as below ans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the using L.CRS.simple and trying to draw a circle. 
When circles are drawn (L.Draw.circle_drawShape()) the radius is set from the result of L.LatLng.distanceTo and this distance is actually calculated based on L.CRS.Earth

When L.CRS.Smple is used the radius becomes really huge, going out of bounds. 
While drawing other shapes this will not be a problem as they does not use L.LatLng.distanceTo method.

As a work around,what you can do this override :

```
L.LatLng.prototype.distanceTo = function (currentPostion) {
    var dx = currentPostion.lng - this.lng;
    var dy = currentPostion.lat - this.lat;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

This will do the trick.

A detailed explanation of the issue is given in the below link : 
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/611

Hope this helps!!!